# Spring Boot - multipart/form-data POST request is working but multipart/form-data PATCH is not working

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I'm trying to build a controller with `PatchMapping` to handle `multipart/form-data`.
`POST` with `multipart/form-data` is working fine. But `PATCH` request always throws `MultipartException` even though the request I'm sending from postman is absolutely correct. I even tried to send `PATCH` without `file1` and `file2` but still getting same issue.

`build.gradle` plugins and dependencies

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'project-report'
    id 'jacoco'
    id "org.sonarqube" version '3.3'
    id 'net.linguica.maven-settings' version '0.5'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive'
    implementation 'com.github.java-json-tools:json-patch:1.13'
    implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.6'
    implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:1.4'
    implementation 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1'
    implementation group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.4'
}
```

`curl`

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'http://localhost:8443/employeeapp/v1/employees/4002494283' \
--header 'X-GP-Request-Id: $3bfc8e1c-ec2f-4d4b-8a82-f856037cb1e4' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form 'update_request="{
  \"emp_attributes\":[
      {
         \"name\":\"dept_id\",
         \"value\":\"123\"
      },
      {
         \"name\":\"email\",
         \"value\":\"joe.doe@gmail.com\"
      }
   ],
   \"user_name\":\"joe.doe@gmail.com\"
}"' \
--form 'file1=@"/file1.txt"' \
--form 'file2=@"/file2.txt"'
```

`Main.java`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

`controller`

```
@PatchMapping(path="/" + EMP_ID_REGEX, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@RequestHeader("X-GP-Request-Id") String UUID,
                                                             @PathVariable ("empId") String empId,
                                                             @Valid @RequestPart("update_request") UpdateRequest updateRequest,
                                                             @RequestPart(value ="file1", required = false) MultipartFile file1,
                                                             @RequestPart(value ="file2", required = false) MultipartFile file2
    ) throws Exception {}
```

**I don't get why `POST` with the same data is working but `PATCH` is not working. Am I missing something at application level?**

Comment: What is the purpose of your `multipartResolver` bean if you're not using any settings exposed by that specific multipart resolver implementation? Spring boot autoconfigures everything itself for the controllers to accept multipart data. Try removing it and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Class `CommonsMultipartResolver` has an `isMultipart` method which determines whether the request contains multipart content. This method returns `false` if the request is not a `POST`.

Here's its code:

```
if (!POST_METHOD.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
    return false;
}
return FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(new ServletRequestContext(request));
```

All you need to do is remove first check. You can do this by overriding the method when creating the bean:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver() {
        @Override
        public boolean isMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(new ServletRequestContext(request));
        }
    };
}
```

PS: If you do not replace `multipartResolver` with your own, then the standard `StandardServletMultipartResolver` will work with both POST and PATCH requests

Answer (score 0):

You have need to modify your curl request.

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'http://localhost:8443/employeeapp/v1/employees/4002494283' \
--header 'X-GP-Request-Id: $3bfc8e1c-ec2f-4d4b-8a82-f856037cb1e4' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form 'update_request="{
  \"emp_attributes\":[
      {
         \"name\":\"dept_id\",
         \"value\":\"123\"
      },
      {
         \"name\":\"email\",
         \"value\":\"joe.doe@gmail.com\"
      }
   ],
   \"user_name\":\"joe.doe@gmail.com\"
}";type=application/json' \
--form 'file1=@"/file1.txt"' \
--form 'file2=@"/file2.txt"'
```

It works for me. Issue with your curl request controller not able to resolve json request part body.

Also For me without `type=application/json` post is also not working.

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. Are you using the same version of springboot that I'm using?

Comment: I am using spring boot 2.7.5.